# What do the differences mean between pyspark SVD Eigenvectors vs. PCA Eigenvectors?

Tags: pyspark, pca, svd

I'm using the SVD and PCA functions in (pyspark) mllib (Spark 2.2.0) as described in this link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html

Suppose we are given the following data objects:

```
[(2, 2), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (1.0, 1.0), (3.0, 3.0)]
```

Applying the `computeSVD()` function yields:

for U: 
`[DenseVector([-0.3922, -0.0]), DenseVector([-0.3922, -0.7071]), DenseVector([-0.3922, -0.0]), DenseVector([-0.3922, 0.7071]), DenseVector([-0.1961, -0.0]), DenseVector([-0.5883, -0.0])]`

and the local dense matrix V:

```
[[-0.70710678 -0.70710678]
 [-0.70710678  0.70710678]]
```

A question at this point: what are actually the Eigenvectors here in spark? Are they in U or in V?

And now the contrast to applying `computePrincipalComponents()`:
this yields:

```
DenseMatrix([[1., 0.],
            [0., 1.]])
```

According to the spark documentation it is stated that "Principal components are stored in a local dense matrix." Thus the result from the PCA should yield the Eigenvectors, but why are they different compared to the Eigenvectors of the local dense matrix V of the SVD? Are they eventually normed?

Thank you in advance for any elaborations on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvector (dense matrix `V`) as a result of performing `computeSVD()` on your dataset denotes a vector  [2x2 matrix] that is a scalar multiple of the linear decomposition of your dataset.

`SVD` finds the **identity vector** that maximizes variance explained by your data, whereas `PCA` seeks to find a set of orthogonal vectors that act as axes (across an arbitrary `N` number of features) that allow your data to be modeled in two dimensions (determined by the set of axes that result in the maximized amount of variance that is explained by the `SVD`).

This is why your `SVD` outputs the identity vector:

```
[[-0.70710678 -0.70710678]
 [-0.70710678  0.70710678]]
```

And `computePrincipalComponents()` results in the following vectors `[1,0]` and `[0,1]`, which happen to coincide with the naturally occurring X and Y axes.

There is a lot of literature about the relationship between `SVD` and how it relates to `PCA`, and why `SVD` is the more stable solution for preserving data integrity due to rounding inaccuracies as a result of computing the product of your dataset by its tranpose matrix (X*X⊤), but you'd be better served with the many highly upvoted posts on `{math|stats}.stackexchange` listed below.

Helpful Related Questions:

- [What is the intuitive relationship between SVD and PCA?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Why SVD on X is preferred to eigendecomposition of XXT in PCA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359397/why-svd-on-x-is-preferred-to-eigendecomposition-of-xx-top-in-pca?noredirect=1&lq=1)